# excel formula creation using nested if statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help creating a formula in excel.  I am essentially looking for estimated revenue per listing.  I am assuming each booking always has 2 guests - unless it accommodates only 1.  The booking is always for the minimun number of days,  and the extra person charge is per night.  I need to create a nested if statement, but keep running into mental road blocks.  I have some sample data:

```
Accommodates - 4 = A1
Price - 130 = B1
extra people charge - 10 = C1
minimum nights - 4 = D1
```

Comment: What're the statements to do? Cell `A1` has "Accomodates minus 4" ?  What does the input look like, and what do you expect the output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula would be something like:

```
=(Price*MinimumNights)+MAX(Booked-Accomodates,0)*ExtraPersonCharge
```

If you want to include bookings past the minimum amount of nights you can use:

```
=(Price*MAX(Days,MinimumNights))+MAX(Booked-Accomodates,0)*ExtraPersonCharge
```